# how to put text field in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add text field and question over the first radio button in below code.
and after clicking on button it will take me to next question with text field.
how it will work? help me with that.

Flow will remain the same as it is in the current code . but i want to add text field over first radio button text.

```
 <script>
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC,       correct = 0;
var questions = [

[ "What is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B" ],
[ "What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C" ],
[ "What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A" ],
[ "What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C" ]];

function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
  }

function` renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions` correct</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";

    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>";


    <!-- test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>"; -->
}

function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
            choice = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
</script>
```

Comment: You mean js quiz? Try Google `html js quiz`

Comment: yes i want js quiz. @DanielCheung

Comment: Try Google first. Otherwise, you have to show to show your research in your question. Trust me, your solution really isn't complex. Try w3schools for `html inputs`.

Comment: thanks @DanielCheung i am doing that

Answer (score 0):

You can do is use `focus()` function in the *onlclick* event of the radio button. You might also want to add element ID to the radio button to identify the specific radio button or text to focus on.

I do not have enough reputation to add comment so I have to ask here, if you can be more specific on what you exactly want to do, because Text field refers to the text box and I don't see any text box usage in your application.

Comment: i just want a question text and a text field to answer .before those question  which already exist.can you run code on your system so that you can understand well.currently there are four question. i want four more question with text field.each new question should be with the current question.